# Working with offline maps in my simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, mapkit, offline

I can't connect to the internet from my workplace (no need to enter in details), and I started working in an app using mapkit framework. So, my question is simple and plain: Is there any way to setup my simulator to work with maps offline?.

Preferably, I'm looking for something like copying some cached maps into my simulator resources, and do some tweaks for displaying the maps in the simulator as if I were connect to internet.

Note that I have no clue on how to do this:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two approaches with the Mapbox tools:

1. Use the SDK and its `RMTileCache` mechanism for SQLite, disk-backed caches or the MBTiles pre-bundling of map tiles approach.
2. Use MBXMapKit along with MapKit and its disk-backed caching of overlay tiles, possibly replacing all of Apple's maps.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have been able to tell MapKit does not seem to provide a way of caching map tiles, nor does it seem to provide an offline mode.

Instead of using MapKit a number of people seem to reccommend MapBox[1] instead.

[1] https://www.mapbox.com

Comment: Have you cached maps using mapbox?

Comment: No, I have not. I did some googling for you on the MapKit question and found a lot of people asking the same as you (and a number of answers were here on SO). Many people suggested using MapBox though and mentioned it did caching, however, I do not have personal experience with the product, sorry! :(

Comment: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/ Try that page and do a search for `offline` and you should find what you are looking for! :)